# Shouldn't having classes having instances of each other form an infinite loop

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I have two classes that make instances of each other, which probably should create an infinite loop, but they're not. `class` `A` is created first.

```java
class A {

    B[] b = new B[9];

    A() {
        for (each) { // pseudo code
            b[each] = new B(this);
        }
    } 
}
```

```java
class B {

    A a;

    B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    } 
}
```

My Question: Why is this code ***NOT*** making an infinite loop?

Comment: There is no code that creaates a class to start with.

Comment: There is no looping (apart from the loop that creates `B`), thus there is no infinite loop.  There is only a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one `A` instance (if you write `new A()` somewhere) that holds 9 `B` instances and each of them hold a reference to the same `A` instance.

This creates a loop in the sense that the memory of `A` and the `B`s cannot be freed because they reference each other. Other than that there is no problem, no "infinite" loop that would cause any major problems, in particular there is no infinite loop creating more and more objects.

If you wrote

```
class B {

    A a;

    B() {
        this.a = new A();
    } 
}
```

then you would get into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

It won't.. You are just capturing a reference of object of Class A with

```
    this.a = a;
```

and not creating a new one.